# How can I configure SELinux when the semanage command isn't found?

Tags: fedora, security, selinux

I'm having a very hard time configuring SELinux to allow Sending mail.

Looking into selinux documentation I've found I can manage ports via the semanage command, but the command can't be found.

Is there another way to manage ports using SELinux, or a way for me to find this command?

Worst case: Is there a way to disable selinux, or switch to permissive mode without rebooting?

I'm running Fedora.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I see the same thing on Fedora 21 using the XFCE distro. It turns out the default install does not include `policyutils-python`, which contains the command `semanage`.

You can often find out which package contains an item by using:

```
yum provides semanage
```

Answer (score 1):

`semanage` is installed at `/usr/sbin/semanage` on my system — maybe that's just not in your path. It's part of the `policycoreutils` package, which is part of the default install but may be missing (`yum -y install policycoreutils` if it is).

The "big switch" approach is `setenforce Permissive` as root. (And `setenforce Enforcing` to put it back.)

What exactly are you trying to do? One approach is to find the audit log messages from your blocked action, and [use audit2allow to generate a policy module](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/audit2allow). But, there may be a setting in the default Fedora policy which will enable what you want. Run `getsebool -a` to see a list, and use `setsebool` to change it.